# cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText' to 'string' with HtmlEncode AntiXSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, antixsslibrary

Say I wish to encode a `<input>` tag in a user control for my project against XSS using antiXSS.

searchbox.ascx

```
<input id="searchBox" type="text" class="QueryBox" runat="server" />
```

searchbox.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Security.Application;

namespace Project2015.Website.layout.search
{
    public partial class searchbox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchBox = Encoder.HtmlEncode(searchBox);
        }


    }
}
```

I am getting this error when I try to compile my code

> Error 108 Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText' to 'string'
>
> Error 107 The best overloaded method match for
>   'Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(string)' has some
>   invalid arguments

can't see what i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Search box is HTML control. Use text property in encode.

searchBox.Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode(searchBox.Text);

Or you can directly use encode in aspx file.

I suggest it is better to create helper function for encode and use helper function in code. It will be easier to customise later on in case you want to apply some conditions.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Try .Value instead of .Text

Comment: with .Value I get a NullReferenceException

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Project2015.Website.layout.searchbox.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project2015\Website\layout\search\searchbox.ascx.cs:15
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +108
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +164
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +164
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4497

Comment: What values are you entering in text box?